# Android проект. Реализация вкладок

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Привет, я новичок в андроид разработке. Передо мной встала задача реализовать проект со следующим функционалом:

1. с сервера приходят данные, парсятся в объекты
2. требуется динамически создавать вкладки на экране с одиноковой разметкой(включая кнопки и мини-галерею), но разными данными
3. желательно реализовать переключение свайпами

Мой вопрос: какие классы и/или библиотеки следует использовать для достижения результата (пожалуйста, поподробнее).
Спасибо.

Comment: `Retrofit` + `TabLayout` + `ViewPager` + `PagerAdapter` + `Fragment` + `RecyclerView` + `Picasso` + `Button`.

Comment: С помощью `Retrofit` делаете запрос на сервер, получаете коллекцию моделей, допустим это будут ссылки на фотографии в нескольких блоках. Для каждого блока создаете вкладку в `TabLayout` и фрагмент во `ViewPager`, далее в каждом фрагменте создаете сетку фотографий через `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager` и загружаете картинки по ссылкам через `Picasso`